# How to add an int at the end of an uint8_t*?

Tags: c, uint8t

I have a variable :

```
uint8_t* data
```

And I want to add a header to these data. Exactly two numbers.
I want my data like these : data+my_int+my_second_int

After that I have to give my data to a function (that I can't modify), and the size of my data.

Like this : `myfunction(data,size);`

This is currently what my code looks like :

```
struct Data {
  uin8_t* data;
  uint32_t PTS;
  uint32_t DTS;
  uint16_t size_data;
};


struct Data* mydata;
mydata->data = data; // data I get before
mydata->size_daza = size; // size I get before
mydata->PTS = GST_BUFFER_PTS(buf);
mydata->DTS = GST_BUFFER_DTS(buf);

myfunction(mydata,sizeof(struct Data)); // My function , this function add also a header to my data (another).I can't access or modify this function.
```

After this, multiple things happend (doesn't matter what) and at the end another function delete the header appended with 'myfunction',then I cast the data given by this function in struct Data*. I can access to DTS, PTS , size but I have a SIGSEGV error on the data..

I think I have to change my Structure but i don't see an other manner to store a buffer without a pointer.

Comment: Yes, It is a possibility but I want to send my data with UDP.

Comment: ... so? Sending is usually done using a pointer and a size: `sizeof(struct mystruct)`

Comment: Sorry, Exactly this data must be given to another module. And the entry of this module is a uint8_t*. Without sending it with UDP, it is just a function.

Comment: I tried to create a larger uint8_t* table. But when I add my int at the end of it, it is not added entirely. For example : if my int is 70000000 , 42C1D80 in hex, I'll have just '80' in my data.

Comment: The sending function only takes a pointer? No size? Then the size is probably hard coded, meaning you couldn't send more than a single byte.

Comment: No the size too of course, sorry

Comment: I guess it would be good if you added that context info to the question, showing how you want to use it.

Comment: It would be much better if you paste the related code , such as `myfunction(data,size);`

Comment: You might want to tell us **how `myfunction()` handles** the data. Without knowing this, it is not possible to answer.

Comment: I don't know exactly. I just know that it is appending another header to my data.

Comment: The way you have the structure set up, it appears that the buffer sent to `myfunction` is contains a pointer to the data and not the data itself.  Is this what it expects?  Like alk said, we need to know exactly what `myfunction` expects in the buffer sent to it.

Comment: myFunction is just adding an other header to the data i give to it. For example, i can give it a video buffer and it appends some stuff to my buffer. Here I want to give it more than just the data (I want data+timestamps). How can I give the data itself and not the pointer ?

Comment: Anyone know how to have all the data and not just a pointer ?

Answer (score 0):

That is what structures are for. You define the structure of the data you want to send:

```
struct Data {
  uint8_t data;
  int first_int;
  int second_int;
  // possibly more
};
```

And pass it to the sending function, in form of a pointer to the start of the
occupied memory (this is usually a `void *`) and the corresponding size:

```
struct Data * mydata = // ... wherever that comes from
send_somewhere(mydata, sizeof(struct Data));
// look at the API doc if you are still the owner of the
// memory and if so, free it (if it's no longer needed and
// has been dynamically allocated)
```

Depending on how `send_somewhere` is implemented (e.g. if it doesn't take a
`void *`), you may need to cast it,
e.g. in the case you're describing:

```
send_somewhere((uint8_t*)mydata, sizeof(struct Data));
```

There is a possible drawback: Structures may get padded by an optimizing
compiler. Padding means that you'd send more data than you actually need to send. Depending on the compiler there are attributes to
disallow padding:

```
struct Data {
  // contenst
} __attribute__((__packed__)); // for gcc, and clang
```

Comment: Thanks, but when the function will read mydata, it will be just a table ?
Because this function accepts just buffers.

Comment: Yes, the function sees the start of some memory plus its size and has no idea what is contained inside that memory.

Comment: It doesn"t work with the function (I have not access to the code inside this function, it's a imported library), I have got a SIGSEGV error...

Comment: Could you post more code. Currently this is just guessing :)

Comment: I forgot to malloc ;)

Comment: The OP is talking about `uint8_t * data;` not about `uint8_t data;`.

Comment: Yes, it's a uint8_t * data; , can this solution be possible with a pointer ?

Comment: No, sending a pointer will never work (or better: do what you want), you should only send what the pointer points to.

Comment: Ok, but how can I change uint8_t* data ( or void* data), to pointed data. Because &data is just the beginning of my buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably accessing the appended int value addresses with the uint8_t pointer. Try casting it to an int* when you're accessing them.

Give us your code, orherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: No. This has alignment issues.

Comment: @imallett: ... **might** have alignment issues depending on the number of `uint8_t` placed before the two `int`s.